# no matching function for call

Tags: c++, function, header-files

i am new to c++ and i am currently trying to write a program that uses main to call functions which are seperately written and i tried to write the definitions for the header file declarations and i am getting errors with some functions which i have marked in the code

Store.hpp

```
#ifndef STORE_HPP

#define STORE_HPP
class Product;
class Customer;
#include<string>

#include "Customer.hpp"
#include "Product.hpp"
class Store

{

private:

std::vector<Product*> inventory;

std::vector<Customer*> members;


public:

void addProduct(Product* p);

void addMember(Customer* c);

Product* getProductFromID(std::string);

Customer* getMemberFromID(std::string);

void productSearch(std::string str);

void addProductToMemberCart(std::string pID, std::string mID);

void checkOutMember(std::string mID);

};

#endif
```

i am having trouble writing the code for that function help me

store.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "Customer.hpp"
#include "Store.hpp"
#include "Product.hpp"
using namespace std;

string id;

void Store::addProduct(Product* p)       //error 1 no matching function
{

    Product* p(std::string id, std::string t, std::string d, double p, int qa);
    inventory.push_back(p);
}

void Store:: addMember(Customer* c)
{
    members.push_back(c->getAccountID());
}

Product*  Store::getProductFromID(std::string id)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++)
    {
        Product* p=inventory.at(i);
        if(p->getIdCode()= id)
        {
            return p;
        }
}
    return NULL;
}
Customer* Store:: getMemberFromID(std::string id)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < members.size(); i++)
    {
        Customer* c = members.at(i);
        if(c->getAccountID() == id)
        {

            return c;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
void std::Store productSearch(std::string str)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++)
    {
        if(inventory[i] == str)
        {
            Product stud(inventory[i],inventory[i+1],inventory[i+2],inventory[i+3],inventory[i+4]);
cout<<getIdCode();

cout<<getTitle();

cout<<getDescription();

cout<<getPrice();

cout<<getQuantityAvailable();
        }
    }
}
void addProductToMemberCart(std::string pID, std::string mID)
{
    cout<<"adding to cart"<<endl;
    getMemberFromID(mID)->addProductToCart(pID);  

}

void checkOutMember(std::string mID)
{
    Customer* c=getAccountID(mID)
    mID=getMemberFromID(std::string mID);
    if(mID=="NULL")
    {
        cout<<mID<<"is not found"<<endl;
    }

}
```

customer.hpp

```
#ifndef CUSTOMER_HPP

#define CUSTOMER_HPP

#include<vector>

#include "Product.hpp"

class Customer

{

private:

std::vector<std::string> cart;

std::string name;

std::string accountID;

bool premiumMember;

public:

Customer(std::string n, std::string a, bool pm);

std::string getAccountID();

//std::vector getCart();

void addProductToCart(std::string);

bool isPremiumMember();

void emptyCart();

};

#endif
```

product.hpp

```
#ifndef PRODUCT_HPP

#define PRODUCT_HPP

#include<vector>

class Product

{

private:

std::string idCode;

std::string title;

std::string description;

double price;

int quantityAvailable;

public:

Product(std::string id, std::string t, std::string d, double p, int qa);

std::string getIdCode();

std::string getTitle();

std::string getDescription();

double getPrice();

int getQuantityAvailable();

void decreaseQuantity();

};

#endif
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: vittorio i am trying to add a product into the vectory inventory and using the function addProduct in the store.hpp and i am having problem on how to write the code for that function which is in store.cpp you can just look at it i have commented the error over there

Comment: You need to minimize your example - you literally posted your entire code. Make a minimal example that reproduces the issue and post that instead.

Comment: hahah okay i'll do that now

Comment: What is the first line of `addProduct` supposed to do? (The thing it does is to declare a function `p` that returns a `Product*`.)

Comment: i was trying to set the values with constructor and save them to the inventory vector

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387937/how-to-write-implmentation-code-for-this-addproduct-function   
@Vittorio i just minimized it and posted again here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to write implmentation code for this addProduct function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387937/how-to-write-implmentation-code-for-this-addproduct-function)

Answer (score 1):

You code issues lots of warnings and errors as stands.
If you find yourself in this situation and can't figure out what one of them means, try to fix some of the others.

Your main problem is in `addProduct`, but there are others

```
using namespace std;

string id; //<---- what's this for?

void Store::addProduct(Product* p)       //error 1 no matching function
{

    //Product* p(std::string id, std::string t, std::string d, double p, int qa); 
    //<--- This line had the error and isn't needed
    inventory.push_back(p);
}

void Store::addMember(Customer* c)
{
//  members.push_back(c->getAccountID()); //<--- this errors too
    members.push_back(c);
}

Product*  Store::getProductFromID(std::string id)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++)
    {
        Product* p = inventory.at(i);
        //if (p->getIdCode() = id) //<-- be careful with = and ==
        if (p->getIdCode() == id) //<---
        {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

Customer* Store::getMemberFromID(std::string id)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < members.size(); i++)
    {
        Customer* c = members.at(i);
        if (c->getAccountID() == id)
        {
            return c;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

//void std::Store productSearch(std::string str) 
void Store::productSearch(std::string str) // <---- note this change too
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++)
    {
        //if (inventory[i] == str) //<<--------!
        if (inventory[i]->getDescription() == str)
        {
            //Product stud(inventory[i], inventory[i + 1], inventory[i + 2], inventory[i + 3], inventory[i + 4]); 
            // This is five Products from the inventory, not the i-th product in your invetory
            Product stud(*inventory[i]);//<---- I assume                
            cout << stud.getIdCode();
            cout << stud.getTitle();
            cout << stud.getDescription();
            cout << stud.getPrice();
            cout << stud.getQuantityAvailable();
        }
    }
}

void Store::addProductToMemberCart(std::string pID, std::string mID)//<--- note note std::Store addProductToMemberCart
{
    cout << "adding to cart" << endl;
    getMemberFromID(mID)->addProductToCart(pID);

}

void Store::checkOutMember(std::string mID)//<---
{
    //Customer* c = getAccountID(mID);//<<---?
        //mID = getMemberFromID(std::string mID);  //<---?
    Customer* c = getMemberFromID(mID); //Just this?
    if (c == NULL)//<---rather than "NULL" but nullptr might be better
    {             //  or not using pointers at all
        cout << mID << "is not found" << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: thankyou so much @doctorlove u really helped me a lot still having some questions and errors

Comment: how to write for checkoutmember still having problem with checkoutmember thanks in advance
Customer* c = Store::getMemberFromID(mID); i have changed to this inside the checkoutmember

Comment: got it thanqq again