# how to write implmentation code for this addProduct function

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and I am having trouble writing the code for that function. I just need it to store product values which are ID, name, description of the product, price, and quantity into the vector inventory.

Store.hpp

```
#ifndef STORE_HPP

#define STORE_HPP
class Product;
class Customer;
#include<string>

#include "Customer.hpp"
#include "Product.hpp"

class Store
{
private:
    std::vector<Product*> inventory;
    std::vector<Customer*> members;

public:
    void addProduct(Product* p);
    void addMember(Customer* c);
    Product* getProductFromID(std::string);
    Customer* getMemberFromID(std::string);
    void productSearch(std::string str);
    void addProductToMemberCart(std::string pID, std::string mID);
    void checkOutMember(std::string mID);
};

#endif
```

I tried to write it in this manner. I know it is wrong please help me out.

Thanks in advance

```
void Store::addProduct(Product* p)
{
    Product* p(std::string id, std::string t, std::string d, double p, int qa);
    inventory.push_back(p);
}
```

Comment: You seem to be confused about what a pointer is and when to use one. Please brush up on that first. The `addProduct` member function already receives a pointer to the instance of the `Product` class, why do you use the constructor and where are you expecting the information such as `id` to come from?

Comment: but i get an error saying [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::vector<Product*>::push_back(Product* (&)(std::string, std::string, std::string, double, int))'

Comment: @riodoro1 please tell me how to write the code to store in the vector

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a complete object by p pointer and push it to the vector, it would look the same, but without string `Product* p(std::string id, std::string t, std::string d, double p, int qa);` Also you can create a copy of your Product, this way is valid if you have a copy constructor.

```
void Store::addProduct(Product* p)
{

    Product* copyOfP = new Product(*p);
    inventory.push_back(copyOfP);
}
```

Or another not very good way:
    void Store::addProduct(Product* p)
    {

```
    Product* copyOfP = new Product(p->getId(), p->getT(), p->getD, ... );
    inventory.push_back(copyOfP);
}
```

If you choose a variant with copies - don't forget to delete them manually in destructor of Store.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
void Store::addProduct(Product* p)
{
    Product* p(std::string id, std::string t, std::string d, double p, int qa);
    inventory.push_back(p);
}
```

might issue a warning - you have redeclared the formal parameter `p`.

The line

```
    Product* p(std::string id, std::string t, std::string d, double p, int qa);
```

looks like a function declaration for something return a pointer to a `Product`. You sent a `Product` pointer in to the function, so just use that:

```
void Store::addProduct(Product* p)
{
    inventory.push_back(p);
}
```

You are trying to push_back the function `p` - don't ignore warnings.